# How can I filter a content query web part reading from a task list to include only tasks assigned to current user?

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have an intranet based on SharePoint 2010 that uses Active directory for authentication.

I have a Content Query web part that display tasks from the tasks lists. All users have access to the tasks list.
How can I filter the data in the Content Query web part to only show the tasks assigned to the current user ?

Can this be done or do I need to create a custom web part to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution might be to use the  User Tasks web part. Although it doesn't make it obvious, this can be made query across the entire site collection, for either 2007 or 2010.

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-user-tasks-web-part-display-all-tasks/

Answer (score 3):

In 2007, when you select a coulmn to filter on that is a person/group field, there is an option to filter by Me.  This works the same as any regular list/library where you have views filtered by the current logged in user.  The CQWP works the same way.

I assume there is something similar in 2010, I don't have a farm to view that in specficly at this time.